# Issue in Login with Facebook Account in android Application

Tags: android, facebook

I want to implement "Login with Facebook" in my Android application, so I followed all the steps explained on the Facebook Developers site. My code is :

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.LoggingBehavior;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.Settings;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String URL_PREFIX_FRIENDS = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=";
private TextView textInstructionsOrLink;

Button mButton;
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    textInstructionsOrLink=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tex);

    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    }
    updateView();   
}
private void updateView() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) {
      if (session.isOpened()) {

            // make request to the /me API
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback()    {

              // callback after Graph API response with user object
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {

                    System.out.println("Name " + user.getName() );
                    textInstructionsOrLink.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                }
              }
            });
          }
        mButton.setText("Logout");
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogout(); }
        });
    } 
    else {
    textInstructionsOrLink.setText("Intri");
    mButton.setText("Login");
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
    });
    }
}
private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
      session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
    } else {
       Session.openActiveSession(this, true,statusCallback);
    }
}

private void onClickLogout() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
}

private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        updateView();
    }
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

**My Manifest.xml is as follow;**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fbtest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fbtest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />

   <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />
   </application>
 </manifest>
```

The above code works fine in the Emulator, but doesn't work on a real device. After login, the button's text doesn't change to "Logout", and the username isn't properly displayed. Can you help me to solve it ?

Comment: Try printing out the "exception" field in your Session.StatusCallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I SOlve problem i run above code with different HAskkey value when i change with my system hashkey value it is running fine